# IOS6: Storyboard Localization does't work for placeholder of a searchbar

Tags: localization, storyboard, ios6, xcode4.5

I'm using the iOS6 new localization workflow can share a single base .storyboard file for multiple locales.

The problem is placeholder field of UISearchBar doesn't get localized.

Below is two string files for localization.

- For English strings file for placeholder

  > /* Class = "IBUISearchBar"; placeholder = "Search"; ObjectID =
  >   "ZCN-Up-u9q"; */ "ZCN-Up-u9q.placeholder" = "Search";
- Other language string file for placeholder

  > /* Class = "IBUISearchBar"; placeholder = "Search"; ObjectID =
  >   "ZCN-Up-u9q"; */ "ZCN-Up-u9q.placeholder" = "搜索";

Does any one have the same problem?

Comment: Facing the same issue :(

Comment: [Here has a workaround for it in a similar post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075165/storyboard-base-localization-strings-file-does-not-localize-at-runtime