# Storyboard + base localization + .strings file does not localize at runtime

Tags: ios, ios6, localization, storyboard

(There are similar questions. Some resulted in answers that I've tried and found not to work. Others got no answers, I assume because the querents didn't supply as much detail as I'm about to.)

I started with a storyboard that worked well for my app; the strings it contains are in English. I wanted to add a French localization. I did this:

- Added a base localization, which transferred
  `MainStoryboard.storyboard` from `en.lproj` to `Base.lproj`.
- Added a French localization, which cloned `InfoPlist.strings` (English)
  and `MainStoryboard.storyboard` (Base) into `fr.lproj`.
- Changed a couple of strings (titles of segments in a
  `UISegmentedControl`) in the French `MainStoryboard.storyboard`.
- In the Simulator, set the language to French.
- Ran the app from Xcode.

**Result**: This worked; my changed strings showed up in the running application.

But I want to be all fancy. I want to do the French localization using a `.strings` file. (It's not just a matter of being fancy; the French localization will be turned over to nontechnical translators, who can't be expected to master Interface Builder.) So:

- Selected the base `MainStoryboard.storyboard` in the Xcode Project
  navigator.
- In the File inspector, under Localization, changed the French
  localization from "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Storyboard" to
  "Localizable Strings."
- Accepted Xcode's warning that the French storyboard will be discarded
  in favor of a `.strings` file, which appears in the Assistant editor.
- Made the same two edits; there's no question of their being the wrong
  strings, because they're all commented as
  `IBUISegmentedControl...segmentTitles`; and the label text doesn't
  appear anywhere else in the `.strings` file.
- Deleted the existing (working) copy of the app from the simulator.
- Ran the app.

**Result**: The view uses the base (originally English) localization, instead of loading the French strings.

This isn't satisfactory. I've tried deleting the app from the simulator, and even deleting the derived-data folder. The bug persists.

As I said, I can't turn a `.storyboard` file over to a nontechnical translator. How can I get iOS to accept the storyboard localizations from a `.strings` file?

Comment: Converting the storyboard to Auto Layout had no effect.

Comment: A response to another similar question suggested running ibtool on the base storyboard, and using that as a starter for the .strings file instead of the one Interface Builder provided. The two files are identical.

Comment: Here's another variable: The storyboard has a lot of unreachable scenes: They aren't the initial controller, and they don't have any segues leading into them. (Not my doing; I'll have to speak to the developer who thought this was a good idea.)

Could that interfere with .strings localization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem with my `UISegmentedControl`s. It turns out that there is a bug in iOS 6: .strings storyboard localization won't work on `UISegmentedControl` text and on `UISearchBar` placeholders.
See this openradar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2159402

Have you tried localizing other elements such as `UILabel`s? That should work.

Comment: I had the same problem, with only a UISearchBar not being localized, while all other stuff did work. The solution described by Susan Sabaria below is a fine workaround for this bug which easily is easily extended to scope titles as well.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I solved it:

in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.segmentedControl setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Title", @"Your localize comment") forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

You can do the same for the search placeholder:

```
[self.searchBar setPlaceholder:NSLocalizedString(@"Your string placeholder", @"Your comment for localizers")];
```

Then just create a Localizable.strings file and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For people developing for **iOS 7 or higher** and searching for the `.strings` format for a search bar, this is how you should translate the `placeholder` field for example:

```
/* Class = "UISearchBar"; normalTitle = "Search for Places"; ObjectID = "F3d-Ir-fni"; */
"F3d-Ir-fni.placeholder" = "Nach Orten suchen";
```