# iOS localization does not work in Xcode for custom labels in objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilabel, xcode5

I implemented a custom view inheriting from UILabel

```
@interface SPLabel : UILabel
```

because I wanted to set all labels in my app with a specific font, therefore the only thing I do with this new class is setting the font I like both in the constructor and in the *awakeFromNib* method.

I then use this SPLabel both in the code and in the Storyboard as a normal UILabel (in the storyboard I modify the custom class of the UILabel object from the inspector or I manually modify the tags with the property *customClass="SMFLabel"*).

Everything worked fine as far as I decided to localize the app and translate it.

The storyboard localization process works fine because it creates me all strings files with label text and it actually apply the translation in all cases BUT on SPLabel.

Am i missing something or it is just something Xcode and iOS are unable to handle?

I am sure the problem is coming from the label customization because as soon as I remove the custom class to one label in the storyboard, the translation works.

thanks for your help

Comment: Use appearance proxy to set font for all labels. For further help you will have to give us all relevant code.

Comment: You might want to ask this in the "AskDifferent" discussion if you haven't already.

Comment: @Eric, this is a programming question. Stackoverflow is the right place.

Comment: Show the code. How do you set / create the labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to localize your custom label title, you could use a `localizable.strings` file, and set its title via code

```
NSString *NSLocalizedString(NSString *key, NSString *comment)
```

Storyboard localization doesn't seem to work for some elements, such as custom labels or e.g. Attributed strings. Not sure if it's a bug or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this some behavior you were already aware of? Unfortunately I think I will go for dynamically setting the text in all UILabel in the storyboard, as you suggested. But it will really take me loong time.

Comment: Yes, I ran into this type of issue earlier this year, specifically with attributed strings. But se has a number of other examples, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075165/storyboard-base-localization-strings-file-does-not-localize-at-runtime regarding UISegmentedControl and UISearchBar. It seems that, at the moment at least, Apple expects you to localize certain components in certain ways, and localization via IB (as much improved as it is in XCode 5 vs earlier versions) is not available for everything yet.

Comment: Ok so it seems the only solution it's to use dynamic localized strings. thanks.

Comment: Anyone please provide swift code of above :(